# ASP MVC - Having different action handlers invoked depending on query params?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, action

I would like different a different action to handle a request depending on query parameters values.

For example:

mydomain.com/controller/action?version=1&msg=hello

and

mydomain.com/controller/action?version=2&msg=5

should go to a different handlers based on the version value.

The list of query params required/optional, as well as their types might change - in version=1, msg is a string, in version=2 it is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Route Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460520(VS.100).aspx):

```
routes.MapRoute("first", "/controller/action/{version}/{msg}", 
    new {controller = "controller", action = "action", 
        version = String.Empty, msg = String.Empty},
    new {version = "1"});

routes.MapRoute("first", "/controller/action/{version}/{msg}", 
    new {controller = "controller", action = "action2", 
        version = String.Empty, msg = String.Empty},
    new {version = "2"});
```